# swift tuple has unexpected print result

Tags: swift

The following code in playground works as expected.

```
let abc = 5.0
let def = 10.0
let tuple = (a: abc, d: def)
println("   tuple Parts  .0 = \(tuple.0)  .1 = \(tuple.1) ")
println("   tuple Parts  .a = \(tuple.a)  .d = \(tuple.d) ")
println("   tuple Whole = \(tuple)")
```

Playground console output:

```
tuple Parts  .0 = 5.0  .1 = 10.0 
tuple Parts  .a = 5.0  .d = 10.0 
tuple Whole = (5.0, 10.0)
```

When that code is placed in a function in a swift class, and a build/run done, the console shows:

```
tuple Parts  .0 = 5.0  .1 = 10.0
tuple Parts  .a = 5.0  .d = 10.0 
tuple Whole = (1.28601959704862e-313, 1.28601959783912e-313)
```

The **Whole** is showing numbers that are almost zero.   Running Beta 2.

What am I overlooking?
Also curious is that placing the println lines in a loop prints out slightly different e-313 values for each repitition of the **Whole** line.

**MORE** For those requesting the rest of the code, there isn't much.

A minimalist, quick and dirty, "full code example" is to create a new project, an iOS Application, choosing Single View Application.  Swift Language selected.

Add a tryTuple function to the View Controller and a call to that function in viewDidLoad.

ViewController.swift looks like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func tryTuple (marker:String) {

    println("---- \(marker)")
    let abc = 5.0
    let def = 10.0
    let tuple = (a: abc, d: def)
    println("   tuple Parts  .0 = \(tuple.0)  .1 = \(tuple.1) ")
    println("   tuple Parts  .a = \(tuple.a)  .d = \(tuple.d) ")
    println("   tuple Whole = \(tuple)")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tryTuple("TryTuple1")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Run of this (pressing the Build and Run cursor in XCODE, happen to be using iPhone 4s iOS simulator) produces this console output.

```
---- TryTuple1
   tuple Parts  .0 = 5.0  .1 = 10.0 
   tuple Parts  .a = 5.0  .d = 10.0 
   tuple Whole = (1.28543029649464e-313, 1.28543029728515e-313)
```

So still isn't what I expect.

Comment: works for me, post full code

Comment: I agree with @BryanChen. "When that code is placed in a function in a swift class, and a build/run done" could mean anything or nothing. You can't run that code at top level of a file, so how _are_ you running it?

Comment: @matt sure you can, at the top level of a main.swift file (the entry point for command-line applications, for example) - still, I've also been unable to repro  :)  let's see the rest of the code! and how did this get question get voted up? seems abandoned, and not particularly useful

Comment: @fqdn I haven't tried a command-line application so I didn't think of that. In the files I've used, statements like `println` are illegal at top level.

Comment: Question asked today, so don't think it is abandoned.  My expectation is that a string from a tuple has the same contents whether playground displayed or placed in a UITextView.  It would be nice to resolve why it is not the same, even if it is my mistake.

Comment: [works for me in REPL](http://pastebin.com/iGKgEe6p), so maybe ios swift library have a bug but not REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. You don't need to put this into a separate function; just putting this:

```
    let foo = (5.0, 10.0)
    println("foo: \(foo)")
```

...into viewDidLoad in an iOS project will reproduce the problem *when run on a 32-bit simulator*, as far as I can tell. This may explain why you can't reproduce it in a playground: I'm guessing your playground will be 64-bit. If I run the above code on a 4S simulator, it prints zeroes, if I run it in a 5S simulator, it prints the expected values.

I'd [file a bug](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) if I were you.

Comment: I agree.  Thanks.  A bug report submitted.