# Decimal values in tuple give garbage values in Swift

Tags: ios, tuples, swift

Decimal values in tuple give garbage value

```
let qwerty = ("Rachit", 5.55)
println(qwerty)
```

It will give output **(Rachit, 1.28416751252943e-313)**

**while**

```
println(qwerty.1)
```

It will give output **5.55**

Why?

Comment: I think we can access tuple by index value if we cannot pass the specific name to particular index of tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a Bug . You Can Refer 
[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356081/swift-tuple-has-unexpected-print-result)

Mainly we don't use whole tuple as you used.We used its Values using .0/.1 or using somename
Like

```
 let http200Status = (statusCode: 200, description: "OK")

        println("The status code is \(http200Status.statusCode)")
        // prints "The status code is 200"
        println("The status message is \(http200Status.description)")
        // prints "The status message is OK”
```